# Links with CSS background images jump when hovered

Tags: html, css

As said in the title, I've got a small problem with my CSS hover images.

They jump/get squeezed when hovered in Safari (sometimes it disappear when downsizing the browser) and Chrome.

It's barely visible as it's like 1px wide but it's here.

I was assuming it was due to the responsiveness of the website and to the fact that the images are downsized.

But when I tried it in Firefox, it handled it like a boss, no weird jumps on hover (but some serious aliasing, duh).

Thanks for your help.

So here is a code snippet of the problem (images are NSFW) :

```css
a, abbr, acronym, address, applet, article, aside, audio, b, big, blockquote, body, canvas, caption, center, cite, code, dd, del, details, dfn, div, dl, dt, em, embed, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, html, i, iframe, img, ins, kbd, label, legend, li, mark, menu, nav, object, ol, output, p, pre, q, ruby, s, samp, section, small, span, strike, strong, sub, summary, sup, table, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, time, tr, tt, u, ul, var, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
body, html, pre {
    color: #292a2c;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.project-panel {
    background: #eaeaea;
    padding: 1.6666666666666667rem 0rem;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
a, abbr, acronym, address, applet, article, aside, audio, b, big, blockquote, body, canvas, caption, center, cite, code, dd, del, details, dfn, div, dl, dt, em, embed, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, html, i, iframe, img, ins, kbd, label, legend, li, mark, menu, nav, object, ol, output, p, pre, q, ruby, s, samp, section, small, span, strike, strong, sub, summary, sup, table, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, time, tr, tt, u, ul, var, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.project-panel .pp-thumb a {
    display: inline-block;
}
.container {
    max-width: 1290px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1170px)
.container-fluid, .container, .admin-container {
    padding: 0 3.33333rem 0 3.33333rem;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.admin-container, .container, .container-fluid {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 0 1.66667rem;
}
.admin-container, .container {
    max-width: 1230px;
    width: 100%;
}
*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
body, html {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.66667;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1170px)
.row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
.grid-row, .row {
    flex: auto;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}
.admin-row, .grid-row, .row {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: -.83333rem;
    margin-right: -.83333rem;
}
.project-panel .pp-thumb {
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1170px)
.column, .grid-column {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
[data-breakpoint=md] [data-md-width='2'], [data-breakpoint=lg] [data-lg-width='2'], [data-breakpoint=xl] [data-xl-width='2'], [data-xl-width='2'] {
    width: 16.66667%;
    max-width: 16.66667%;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex-basis: 16.66667%;
}
.project-panel .pp-thumb img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.project-panel .pp-thumb a {
    display: inline-block;
}
body::after{
    position:absolute; width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:-1;
    content:url(https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/logo-Couillart.gif) url(https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Danger-Zone-Logo-website-thumbnail.gif) url(https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Thicc-girls-slim-boi.gif) url(https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/trio-trompettes-rouge-1.gif) url(https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/chauve-souris-anim.gif) url(https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/logo-Couillart-blanc.gif);
}
.project-panel .pp-thumb a {
    display: inline-block;
}
.project-panel .pp-thumb a:hover > img {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.project-panel .pp-thumb a[title="Danger Zone"] {
 background: url(https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Danger-Zone-Logo-website-thumbnail.gif) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
.project-panel .pp-thumb a[title="Dangerz"] {
  background: url(https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Thicc-girls-slim-boi.gif) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
.project-panel .pp-thumb a[title="Danger II"] {
  background: url(https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/trio-trompettes-rouge-1.gif) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
.project-panel .pp-thumb a[title="About"] {
  background: url(https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/chauve-souris-anim.gif) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
.footercustom {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
 margin-bottom: 0 !important;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
<section class="project-panel" data-pp-gutter="yes">
    <div class="container" data-title-visibility="hidden" data-meta-visibility="hidden">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="column" data-xl-width="12">
       <p class="panel-label"><span data-font="regular"></span></p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row pp-thumbs">
      
     <div class="pp-thumb column" data-xl-width="2" data-sm-width="4" data-xs-width="6">
      <a href="https://couill.art/project/danger-zone" title="Danger Zone"><img src="https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Danger-Zone-Logo-website-thumbnail-0-00-00-00.png" width="340" height="255"></a>
      <p class="pp-title"><a data-font="font_dqju2lgtu" href="https://couill.art/project/danger-zone" title="Danger Zone">Danger Zone</a><span data-font="font_dqju2lgtu">Animation</span></p>
     </div>
   
     <div class="pp-thumb column" data-xl-width="2" data-sm-width="4" data-xs-width="6">
      <a href="https://couill.art/project/about-duplicate-2" title="Dangerz"><img src="https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Thicc-girls-slim-boi-0-00-25-18.png" width="340" height="255"></a>
      <p class="pp-title"><a data-font="font_dqju2lgtu" href="https://couill.art/project/about-duplicate-2" title="Dangerz">Dangerz</a><span data-font="font_dqju2lgtu">Animation</span></p>
     </div>
   
     <div class="pp-thumb column" data-xl-width="2" data-sm-width="4" data-xs-width="6">
      <a href="https://couill.art/project/danger-zone-duplicate" title="Danger Zone"><img src="https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Danger-Zone-Logo-website-thumbnail-0-00-00-00.png" width="340" height="255"></a>
      <p class="pp-title"><a data-font="font_dqju2lgtu" href="https://couill.art/project/danger-zone-duplicate" title="Danger Zone">Danger Zone</a><span data-font="font_dqju2lgtu">Animation</span></p>
     </div>
   
     <div class="pp-thumb column" data-xl-width="2" data-sm-width="4" data-xs-width="6">
      <a href="https://couill.art/project/about-duplicate" title="About"><img src="https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/chauve-souris-anim-0-00-00-00.png" width="340" height="255"></a>
      <p class="pp-title"><a data-font="font_dqju2lgtu" href="https://couill.art/project/about-duplicate" title="About">About</a><span data-font="font_dqju2lgtu">Animation</span></p>
     </div>
   
     <div class="pp-thumb column" data-xl-width="2" data-sm-width="4" data-xs-width="6">
      <a href="https://couill.art/project/danger-ii-duplicate" title="Danger II"><img src="https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/trio-trompettes-rouge-0-00-32-12.png" width="340" height="255"></a>
      <p class="pp-title"><a data-font="font_dqju2lgtu" href="https://couill.art/project/danger-ii-duplicate" title="Danger II">Danger II</a><span data-font="font_dqju2lgtu">Animation</span></p>
     </div>
   
     <div class="pp-thumb column" data-xl-width="2" data-sm-width="4" data-xs-width="6">
      <a href="https://couill.art/project/about" title="About"><img src="https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/chauve-souris-anim-0-00-00-00.png" width="340" height="255"></a>
      <p class="pp-title"><a data-font="font_dqju2lgtu" href="https://couill.art/project/about" title="About">About</a><span data-font="font_dqju2lgtu">About</span></p>
     </div>
   
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your preloading technique is solid, but you need to remove the double slashes from the url's in the declarations for `:hover`.

The browser (Chrome) sees them as different images:

`https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Danger-Zone-Logo-website-thumbnail.gif`
`https://couill.art//wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Danger-Zone-Logo-website-thumbnail.gif`

**Edit:** This resolves flickering on Chrome, but causes it on Firefox. The fix, it turns out, is that you don't actually need to target the `a` elements `:hover`. The `img` tag covers up the background of the `a` elements anyway, so just use:

```
  .project-panel .pp-thumb a[title="Danger Zone"] {
    background: url(https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Danger-Zone-Logo-website-thumbnail.gif) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
  }
```

When the `img` is hovered, its visibility is set to `hidden` and then the animation behind is shown without flicker.

Here is the relevant working CSS:

```
  .project-panel .pp-thumb a[title="Danger Zone"] {
    background: url(https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Danger-Zone-Logo-website-thumbnail.gif) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
  }
  .project-panel .pp-thumb a[title="Dangerz"] {
    background: url(https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Thicc-girls-slim-boi.gif) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
  }
  .project-panel .pp-thumb a[title="Danger II"] {
    background: url(https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/trio-trompettes-rouge-1.gif) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
  }
  .project-panel .pp-thumb a[title="About"] {
    background: url(https://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/chauve-souris-anim.gif) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
  }
```

And [here is a live example](http://dynamic-teaching.surge.sh).

Comment: Thanks! But I think I just made a typo when creating the snippet. I looked at the code of my website and didn't see any of those double slashes anywhere.

Comment: I also don't see how your answer relates to my question.

Comment: Ok. It relates because you said the images were flickering on hover in chrome, and using the code I posted prevents the flicker in Chrome (latest stable on macOS), as seen [here](http://royal-pear.surge.sh/)

Comment: What's interesting is that the fix for Chrome causes flickering again in Firefox. So indeed my answer doesn't solve the overall problem :)

Comment: ah okay, that's weird cause when I click on your example it's the same as my snippet, flickering in Safari and Chrome but looking smooth in Firefox  (tried on  OSX Chrome 67.0.3396.79)

Comment: Ahh, thank you a lot, didn't thought about that coding pleonasm! This resolved the problem in Safari, but not in Chrome (both on my website and your live example with cache flushed multiple times). Do you have an idea of what's wrong on my side ?

Comment: Finally after some testing in turns out to be better with your improved code but the problem is still here depending on how the browser window is sized (on Safari and Chrome).

Comment: I think we're officially in the twighlight zone here. No flickering on my side in Chrome, FF, Safari in private browsing windows with caches flushed, in various window sizes.

Comment: Okay, that's frustrating. I'll ask some friends and try on other computers to see if that's just mine. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172723/discussion-between-sh78-and-bolos).